# AWS: How to create a public AMI from instance using Boto3?

Tags: boto3, amazon-ami

I was able to find in the documentation on how to create AMI images from the running instance. But I am not able to change it to public visibility.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=create%20image#EC2.Instance.create_image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the CLI example, you can do this via the command:

aws ec2 modify-image-attribute --image-id ami-0abcdef1234567890 --launch-permission "Add=[{Group=all}]"

So if you want to achieve this using Lambda, you need to use the modify_attribute, resource action.

[1] https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=create%20image#EC2.Image.modify_attribute

Comment: Although I was looking for a boto3 answer, the documentation link pointed me in the right direction, thanks! For those looking for a boto3 answer :: 

Get the image resource and then modify launch permissions... 

imgr=resource.Image(imageid)
 
imgr.modify_attribute(LaunchPermission={'Add':[{'Group':'all'}]})